# Change CSS vertical dropdown menu to horizontal

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I downloaded a CSS dropdown menu from a website(purecss.menus.com). It started off as a vertical menu and when you hover over, the sub menus appear to the right of the menu. I have changed the main menu to display horizontally. But I'm not sure which part of the CSS code to change so that the sub menus appear vertically under the menu item. I've tried changing the width,position and display attributes of `ul ul`, `ul li ul` etc. but can't seem to get it to work.

Here is a [JSfiddle with the code](http://jsfiddle.net/wPK9n/)

Comment: Try changing _top_ and _left_ under _#cssmenu ul ul_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wPK9n/5/) with changes to `#cssmenu ul ul`

Keep in mind that when you change the background to something other than white, you'll see the small arrow, which looks a bit wierd due to the new position.

```
#cssmenu ul ul {
  margin-top: 1px;
  visibility: hidden; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 37px;
  left: -20px; 
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove **left: 99%;** from '#cssmenu ul ul' and replace by below code:

```
#cssmenu ul ul{
    /* left: 99%; Remove this*/
    margin-top: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 598;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wPK9n/6/), with the submenu top space relative to the main menu height:

```
#cssmenu ul ul {
  margin-top: 1px;
  visibility: hidden; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display:inline-block;` in `#cssmenu ul li` and `left: 99%;` to `left: 10%;` in `#cssmenu ul ul`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wPK9n/4/)